# Clarification for Google Apps Script created by "Hyde" - Make some parts of sheet non-editable by code (and apply this to several tabs)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to use the script that "Hyde" created and provided as seen at https://support.google.com/docs/thread/149743347/script-make-some-parts-of-sheet-non-editable-by-code-and-apply-this-to-several-tabs?hl=en. Specifically, I need to use the "// copy sheets '1', '2' and '3' to another spreadsheet" and put them at the end of the tab bar" option in the script, but can't seem to sort out a) where to put what variables, and b) populate them, so the script does what I need it to do. Namely, take an exist Sheets file (will probably be a gallery template IF that would allow the script to work too) with RANGE protection in place on 7 tabs, and create a new Sheets file with the "same" protections. The goal is to allow our employees to make copies (by way of using template if possible) and use the Sheets file, but NOT edit the ranges we have protected. **Only select accounts, excluding "you" in the permissions which is obviously relative, should be able to edit the protected ranges.**

Hyde's script appears to have multiple uses as described in the comments, but it seems some of the variables listed in comments need to be moved out of the comment section and possibly replace other variables/options in place for the default way the script is built to run.

Looking at suggested questions for this post I've reviewed https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection. It seems we may also need to be able to specify something (user or group) other than "me" in "protection.addEditor(me);". Is that possible?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/13045193)

Comment: While links to external content might be helpful, questions on this site should be self contained. Considering this, you should post the relevan parts parts of the the external resource, if the script is large, then you should create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

> The goal is to allow our employees to make copies (by way of using template if possible) and use the Sheets file, but NOT edit the ranges we have protected.

When a user starts a script function through a [button](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets), a [custom menu item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus), or a [sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars), or directly through **Run** in the Script Editor, the function runs under the account of the user at the keyboard. This means that any spreadsheets created by the function will be owned by that user, and the user will thus have full access to any sheets and ranges protected by the function as well.

To do what you are asking, create a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) that runs under an admin account. Any spreadsheets and protections created by the web app will be owned by the account who deployed the web app and not by the account of the user who runs the web app.

An easier solution would be to protect the sheets and ranges with the **Show warning when editing this range** option. These protections are automatically inherited into copies of the spreadsheet. This way, you would not need a script at all — just tell the users to make a copy of the template, and it will automatically be protected. Those protections can be bypassed, but they still let users avoid *unintentional* changes to protected parts of the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and good to know that publishing the script as a web app being required to accomplish the task at hand as far as permissions are concerned. The questions about the script contents itself remain. Is that something you can speak to as well?

Comment: I would recommend that you use the easier solution: **Show warning when editing this range**. To learn scripting, see [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: Yeah, easier for you and easier for me, but not meeting the need as described. Seems Hyde (of Google I believe) provided the script, but Google Workspace corporate support said to post the question here as they don't/won't support it. You are correct. This is my first, and last, post to Stack Overflow.

Comment: There is a solution: create a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) that runs under an admin account. Problem is that it is unlikely that you will find somebody here that will volunteer to write a whole web app from scratch for you, so you should start writing it yourself, and ask here when you need help with your _programming_ questions. See [What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572/13045193)